# How do I make this function printNum get called when I input a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in code, and I would like to know how to make it so that the printNum function would output all numbers from 0 to the number you input.

```
while (print <= num){
    console.log(print);
        print = print + 1;
    }
}

x=100
printNum(x);
```

Comment: How are you expecting the user to input their number?

Comment: you need to write the `function printNum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a maximum limit using `prompt`. Then iterate from `0` up to and equal to the number you input, and `console.log` the value each time:

```js
var max = parseInt(prompt("Enter the maximum number: "));
for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I tried this code and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @NeilDeJesus, if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.